# Fastest way to check if a haystack contains set of needles

Tags: java, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a *haystack string* and I would like to check if it contains any of the *needle strings*. Currently I do it that way:

```
Set<String> needles = ...;

...

String [] pieces = haystack.split(" ");
for (String piece: pieces) {
  if (needles.contains(piece) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

It works, but it is relatively slow.

**Question:** Is there a faster way to accomplish the task?

**Example.**

```
 Haystack: I am a big tasty potato .
 Needles:  big, tasty

 == RUN ==
 I am a big tasty potato .
        |
        [tasty] got a match, we are good!
```

Comment: Convert the needles into a regular OR expression and match the haystack without splitting it.

Comment: Provide example input and output. Why `split` if you just call `contains` anyway?

Comment: @BoristheSpider *.contains* is being called on a set, not a haystack.

Comment: "*faster*" is a very tricky term. Do you mean "lower worst time complexity"? And how slow is the current implementation? Over what actual data?

Comment: @Amit I measure in milliseconds, so *fastest from the practical point of view*.

Comment: That depends on to many variables then, but have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) algorithm. This suits your problem because it build an automaton of all words(needles) and traverse the text(haystack) over the built automaton to find all matching words. Its basically constructs a finite state machine that resembles a trie.

The time complexity is `O(n + m + z)` where
`z` is the total number of occurrences of words in text, `n` is the length of text and `m` is the total number characters in all words.

**Edit 2**

Here is a straight-forward implementation which stop traversing after finding first occurrence of any needle.

```
import java.util.*;

class AhoCorasick {

  static final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 256;

  Node[] nodes;
  int nodeCount;

  public static class Node {
    int parent;
    char charFromParent;
    int suffLink = -1;
    int[] children = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    int[] transitions = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    boolean leaf;

    {
      Arrays.fill(children, -1);
      Arrays.fill(transitions, -1);
    }
  }

  public AhoCorasick(int maxNodes) {
    nodes = new Node[maxNodes];
    // create root
    nodes[0] = new Node();
    nodes[0].suffLink = 0;
    nodes[0].parent = -1;
    nodeCount = 1;
  }

  public void addString(String s) {
    int cur = 0;
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
      int c = ch;
      if (nodes[cur].children[c] == -1) {
        nodes[nodeCount] = new Node();
        nodes[nodeCount].parent = cur;
        nodes[nodeCount].charFromParent = ch;
        nodes[cur].children[c] = nodeCount++;
      }
      cur = nodes[cur].children[c];
    }
    nodes[cur].leaf = true;
  }

  public int suffLink(int nodeIndex) {
    Node node = nodes[nodeIndex];
    if (node.suffLink == -1)
      node.suffLink = node.parent == 0 ? 0 : transition(suffLink(node.parent), node.charFromParent);
    return node.suffLink;
  }

  public int transition(int nodeIndex, char ch) {
    int c = ch;
    Node node = nodes[nodeIndex];
    if (node.transitions[c] == -1)
      node.transitions[c] = node.children[c] != -1 ? node.children[c] : (nodeIndex == 0 ? 0 : transition(suffLink(nodeIndex), ch));
    return node.transitions[c];
  }

  // Usage example
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AhoCorasick ahoCorasick = new AhoCorasick(1000);
    ahoCorasick.addString("big");
    ahoCorasick.addString("tasty");

    String s = "I am a big tasty potato";
    int node = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      node = ahoCorasick.transition(node, s.charAt(i));
      if (ahoCorasick.nodes[node].leaf) {
        System.out.println("A match found! Needle ends at: " + i); // A match found! Needle ends at: 9
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However currently this code will find the end position of any occurrences in text. If you need the starting position and/or the needle, you can trace back from the ending position until finding a space to get the matched word.

This doesn't guaranty speed in worst-case, but should work better on average and best cases.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, uhh I mapped this comment to a macro and messed up. Modified original comment.

Comment: Gave it a try using this implementation: https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick. No improvement :(

Comment: @DenisKulagin I thought you need to find all occurrences of words. After you edited, it seems you can stop after one match, right? Did you give a try by returning after finding one match(instead of traversing to find all occurrences) ? It will surely speed up on most cases.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Check now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally most of your slowdown is the split command. You are way better off searching the one string you have than allocating a crap ton of objects. You'd be better off doing regex, and avoiding new object construction. And using Aho would be quite effective. Assuming your lists are big enough to be troublesome.

```
public class NeedleFinder {
    static final int RANGEPERMITTED = 26;
    NeedleFinder next[];

    public NeedleFinder() {
    }
    public NeedleFinder(String haystack) {
        buildHaystack(haystack);
    }

    public void buildHaystack(String haystack) {
        buildHaystack(this,haystack,0);
    }

    public void buildHaystack(NeedleFinder node, String haystack, int pos) {
        if (pos >= haystack.length()) return;
        char digit = (char) (haystack.charAt(pos) % RANGEPERMITTED);
        if (digit == ' ') {
            buildHaystack(this,haystack,pos+1);
            return;
        }
        if (node.next == null) node.next = new NeedleFinder[RANGEPERMITTED];
        if (node.next[digit] == null) node.next[digit] = new NeedleFinder();
        NeedleFinder nodeNext = node.next[digit];
        buildHaystack(nodeNext,haystack,pos+1);
    }
    public boolean findNeedle(String needle) {
        return findNeedle(this, needle,0);
    }
    private boolean findNeedle(NeedleFinder node, String needle, int pos) {
        if (pos >= needle.length()) return true;
        char digit = (char) (needle.charAt(pos) % RANGEPERMITTED);
        if (node.next == null) return false;
        if (node.next[digit] == null) return false;
        return findNeedle(node.next[digit],needle,pos+1);
    }
}
```

On success, check the contains to make sure it's not a false positive. But, it's fast. We're talking 1/5th the speed of binary search.

Speaking of, binary search is a great idea. It's in the right time complexity alone. Just sort your silly list of haystack strings then when you look through the needles do a binary search. In java these are really basic and items in Collections. Both the .sort() and the .binarySearch() commands. And it's going to be orders of magnitude better than brute.

```
value = Collections.binarySearch(haystackList, needle, strcomp);
```

If value is positive it was found.

```
Collections.sort(words, strcomp);
```

With the strcomp.

```
public Comparator<String> strcomp = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s, String t1) {
        if ((s == null) && (t1 == null)) return 0;
        if (s == null) return 1;
        if (t1 == null) return -1;
        return s.compareTo(t1);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. Consider giving an example in Java.

Comment: By far iterating through needles and checking via *.contains* got the best speed improvent of all!

Comment: It depends on the size. If you have a big enough list of haystack you can do a split and a sort for a simple hlog(h) hit and then find all the needles in n(log(h)) time for n needles iterating through the sorted list of h items. Likewise you could build the Avo tree or even a simple hash table for a reasonable hit. -- But, if everything is small you are better off not manipulating the objects and simply doing the .contains() on the original haystack string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java8 plus with `parallel` streams with `anymatch` function

```
    boolean hi=Arrays.stream(pieces).parallel().anyMatch(i->needle.contains(i));
```

Comment: @Denis Kulagin i tested this above just for fun where set contained 100,000 elements and array contained 225 elements (where match string is at the end in both) so it took me 156 mili seconds on 1.73GHz processor and 3 GB ram ,

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, but it worked out to be extremelly slow on my dataset. I am parallelizing bigger quants of work, like bulks of 1000 haystacks and it shows some boost in the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure `needless` is an instance of a `HashSet` which makes contains a "fast", constant time operation. Next, don't process all of `haystack` if you don't have to... Try this:

```
int i, j, l = haystack.length();
for(i = 0; i < l; i = j + 1) {
  j = haystack.indexOf(' ', i + 1);
  if(j == -1) {
    j = l - 1;
  }
  String hay = haystack.s substring(i, j - 1).trim();
  if(hay.length() > 0 && needles.contains(hay)) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

**note: this is untested and indexes might be off by +-1, as well as some edge cases might exist. use at your own risk.*

Answer (score 0):

If it's really all about speed, and you want to search through a list of items instead of a solid string, you could divide the work into different threads (I'm not sure how many items you're checking with, but if it's not taking minutes, this might not be the way to go)

If you don't need to make the haystack into an array, you could instead iterate through needles, and test haystack via String.contains();